# MySQL query ignores order by clausel

Tags: mysql

For some reason, this query does not work -- it does not give any errors, but does not put fields with no value/0000-00-00 first:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  uid,
  employer,
  cid,
  slug,
  startdate,
  enddate,
 `position`,
  pid,
  tasks,
  subordinates,
  salary,
  country,
  info,
  files,
  added 
FROM
  career 
WHERE uid = '172' 
ORDER BY (enddate IS NULL),
  enddate DESC
```

enddate field format is DATE / 'YYYY-MM-DD', if null, it's '0000-00-00'.

Comment: `YU NO WORK` isn't a good description. Please, add samples of data, table structure and desired result

Comment: Just try ordering by enddate and descent it. ORDER BY enddate DESC.

Comment: Null is not the same as '0000-00-00'. Null means, the value is unknown or does not exists. 0000-00-00 means roughly 2020 years ago

Comment: Mysql docs say 0000-00-00 for DATE type field IS null :)

Comment: @fallenboy Then the Mysql docs are wrong. The SQL `CREATE TABLE dates ( d DATE DEFAULT NULL );
INSERT INTO dates (d) VALUES (NULL), ('0000-00-00');
SELECT 'null', d FROM dates WHERE d IS NULL
UNION 
SELECT 'non-null', d FROM dates WHERE d IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT 'zero', d FROM dates WHERE d = '0000-00-00';` has three rows in the result set (one for each subquery) as opposed to the expected two (as result of the first subquery and no results in the other two subqueries) if `'0000-00-00'` where that same as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution:

```
SELECT ...  ORDER BY IF(enddate='0000-00-00', 0, 1), enddate DESC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `orderby` is correct, try removing the (`enddate IS NULL`) - that should then order properly.

If you want to have the NULL ones first, maybe consider doing two queries.

One with enddate as null - in the where clause, and one where enddate is not null.

Rich

Comment: Unless of course I've just learnt a new thing you can do with  orderby  .